# what is difference between Test Cases and Test Scripts?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, terminology

I know that test cases are written in human readable language, whereas test scripts are written in code and mostly done for automated testing.

But can anyone tell me what else make them different from each other?

Is there any logical difference between them or are these interchangeable terms?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the [test-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_case) is the **what** and the [test-script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_script) is the **how** of the test.

Its possible to defined high level test-cases to describe what needs to be tested.
The test-scripts contain all the detail to really execute the test.

Comment: means they are used together ? there is no boundary defined in what kind of system Test cases will be used and in which test scripts ?

Comment: I would think so, but the thing with terminology is that every standard, every company and every person will give it its own definition. I would always ask what the person in the context that I uses it thinks what it means to be sure. Never trust the definition in testing, because terms are often miss-used.

Answer (score 2):

I think the two tend to be interchangeable but if you are studying for the ISTQB Foundations exam they will give specific definitions for each one.

Also, from my experience people in your team will always ask for test cases, I've never actually heard test scripts being referred to. (outside of Automated Test cases/scripts)

Answer (score 1):

Test Scenario - 
A description of a situation to be tested.

Test Case - 
Contains specific data values for a scenario to be executed under specific conditions to produce a predicted result.

Test Script - 
A set of instructions that define each step to be taken and the expected results of each step.

Answer (score 0):

**Script commonly refers to Automation**

There is difference in using it interchangeably. But scripts generally refers to shell/perl/python scripts in computing. When you consider language(not programming languages) script is a word that refers to a document that has some information. So commonly test script refers to automation...

Answer (score 0):

I am expecting all answers must be aligned, But there is a difference.

1. User[Non-technical] readable steps are mentioned to test particular scenario is called as Test Case
2. User[Technical] readable steps written in programming language are referred as Test Script

**Test Case :**

- A test case is a documentation which specifies input values, expected output and the preconditions for executing the test. [Reference - ISTQB book]
- This terminology mostly used for Manual Testing

**Test Script:**

- A test script in software testing is a set of instructions that will be performed on the system under test to test that the system functions as expected.
- This terminology mostly used for Automation Testing

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, both terms can be used in the manual testing context. As noted by others, test cases are lists of specific steps with an expected outcome. A test script is mostly the same thing, but not as specific. A test script might say" Test that the login page works, and that a password with these properties is required" A test case will have detailed steps about where to type, click or other actions.Both may or may not have input data. A script does not always spell out the exact outcome expected.

Answer (score 0):

In [scripted testing methodology](https://artoftesting.com/scripted-testing) the testing team prepares the documents required in the testing process before the testing phase begins. And then performs the testing with the help of these documents. This approach i.e. planning and preparing testing documents before the actual testing is also used in today’s modern methodologies such as RAD and it is known as scripted testing.

Answer (score 0):

The [software testing services company](https://www.qasource.com/software-testing-company) define and differentiate between the testcases and the testscripts as the following:

Testcases:

1.Testcases are the documented steps that are to be executed in order to test the software product. It is mainly written to execute the tests for any particular feature or any specific part of the software.

2.Testcases define the manual approach for testing

3.Testcases revolve around specific set of inputs that are executed manually

Test scripts:

1.Test Scripts are the set of instructions or short program that are run programmatically with different sets of random data to check the overall functionality of the software. Test scripts are commonly known as Automated tests as well and use different programming languages such as Java, Python etc. as per the testing requirements

2.Test scripts define the automated approach for testing

3.Test scripts coverage is large due to random values generated in the scripts hence, covering larger input areas reducing chances of hidden bugs